# Get specific values from a json file

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

When I try to print the json file I get this:

```
{'results': [{'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.996, 'transcript': 'hi '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.973, 'transcript': "it's my first day of school today "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.956, 'transcript': "I'm feeling nervous "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.898, 'transcript': "what if I don't know anything "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.957, 'transcript': "don't worry just give school a try dad says to take something from home to make me feel less nervous "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.948, 'transcript': "take this hard for your first day because I love you robot I know you'll do great today "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.989, 'transcript': 'thanks dad I love you too '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.81, 'transcript': 'this heart will make me think of you all day '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.911, 'transcript': 'my first class is math '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.909, 'transcript': 'will you try it with me '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.24, 'transcript': 'shapes '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.982, 'transcript': "I don't know much about shapes "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.892, 'transcript': "I'll put them in my computer "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.778, 'transcript': 'I learned three shapes '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.215, 'transcript': 'circle '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.733, 'transcript': 'tri angle '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.918, 'transcript': 'where '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.5, 'transcript': 'well I liked doing math '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.915, 'transcript': "now it's time for art class "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.867, 'transcript': "I haven't made a lot of art before "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.912, 'transcript': 'but I can try right '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.909, 'transcript': "I've never painted before "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.864, 'transcript': 'have you '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.998, 'transcript': "well I'll give it a try "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.603, 'transcript': 'there '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.995, 'transcript': 'what do you think '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.967, 'transcript': 'I am more artistic than I thought '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.752, 'transcript': 'I like art class '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.993, 'transcript': "now it's time for recess "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.773, 'transcript': "that's when we get to play outside "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.978, 'transcript': 'do you want to play with me '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.802, 'transcript': 'Hey look I jungle gym '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.773, 'transcript': "I've never been on a jungle gym before "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.999, 'transcript': 'is this how this is supposed to work '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.646, 'transcript': 'I loved recess '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.943, 'transcript': 'and I love school '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.822, 'transcript': 'I can do so much and I learned some things to '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.707, 'transcript': 'look here comes '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.97, 'transcript': "I'm so proud of you on your first day I have a present for you "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.783, 'transcript': 'I '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.445, 'transcript': 'love '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.346, 'transcript': 'cool '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.451, 'transcript': "it's true "}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.838, 'transcript': 'how do I look '}], 'final': True}, {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.836, 'transcript': 'like a robot who loves school '}], 'final': True}], 'result_index': 0}
```

How do I print only the "transcript" part for each one (basically all of the transcripts)?
I tried to run this code:

```
for string in distros_dict.results.alternatives.items():
    print (value['transcript'])
```

But I got an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'results'
```

I ran

```
print(distros_dict['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
```

which printed the correct first one (I couldn't iterate through it though)

```
hi
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I print only the "transcript" part for each one (basically all of the transcripts).

Comment: but the answer is already in your question...

Comment: >>>` [item['alternatives'][0]['transcript'] for item in distros_dict['results']]` and if you have more than one `alternatives`, then `[item['alternatives'][y]['transcript'] for item in x['results'] for y in range(len(item['alternatives']))]`

Comment: I can only print one at a time, I can't find a way to iterate through it and print all of them. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, I apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the dictionary as following because `distros_dict['results']` is a single list of length 1.

```
for string in distros_dict['results']:
    print(string['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
```

**Output**

```
hi 
it's my first day of school today 
I'm feeling nervous 
what if I don't know anything 
don't worry just give school a try dad says to take something from home to make me feel less nervous 
take this hard for your first day because I love you robot I know you'll do great today 
thanks dad I love you too 
this heart will make me think of you all day 

...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your distros_dict has a couple of arrays in it. The first is the "results" array. You could access that via

```
results_array = distros_dict['results']
```

The resulting array then gives you an array of "alternatives"

```
for result in results_array:
    alternatives_array = result['alternatives']
```

I think you simply need to drill down through the 2 levels of arrays. If you only need the first result you could simply use the `distros_dict['results'][0]` similar to what you had, but in case you have more than one, it may be best to iterate through them.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for item in distros_dict["results"]:
    for alternative in item["alternatives"]:
        print(alternative["transcript"])
```